# SQL Query with Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to run a SQL query with Excel VBA.  I got the query from someone else.

```
    vsql = "SELECT [MyTable].Cust_Name, Sum([MyTable].Amt_Paid) AS SumOfAmt_Paid, " & _
         " Count([MyTable].Unit_Num) AS CountOfUnit_Num  " & _
         "WHERE ((([MyTable].Grp) = ""ABC1"") And " & _
         "(([MyTable].Upload_Date) = [Enter Date:]) And " & _ 
         "(([MyTable].Sub_eEmpl) = [Enter Processor's ID:]))" & _ 
         "GROUP BY [MyTable].Cust_Name " & _
         "HAVING ((([MyTable].Cust_Name) Not Like ""Deposit Total*""))"
```

When I run this query, I'm getting the following error message:  "The SELECT statement includes a reserve word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

I can't figure out what is wrong (plus I've never tried to create a SQL query in VBA that requires the user to enter 2 values (Date / ID)

Any help in getting this resolved would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.......

Comment: `"WHERE ((([MyTable].Grp) = 'ABC1') And "`   `...Not Like 'Deposit Total*'))"`  Use single-quotes around query values.   And what are you doing with `[Enter Date:]` here? - are you replacing that with a date value ?

Comment: @TimWilliams........The requestor is looking for a way for the user to be able to enter a date, like in an input box

Comment: I changed the query to use variables from an Input box but still have the same error message:  "SELECT [AR Data].Cust_Name, Sum([AR Data].Amt_Paid) AS SumOfAmt_Paid, Count([AR Data].Unit_Num) AS CountOfUnit_Num  WHERE ((([AR Data].Grp) = 'V1') And (([AR Data].Upload_Date) = #" & strDate & "# And (([AR Data].Sub_eEmpl) = '" & strUser & "'))" & _
            " FROM [AR Data]" & _
            " GROUP BY [AR Data].Cust_Name" & _
            " HAVING ((([AR Data].Cust_Name) Not Like 'Deposit Total*'))"

Comment: That last HAVING clause should just be a regular WHERE clause

Comment: Don't build the SQL statement in one string, build it up piece by piece.

Comment: You don't have a `FROM` clause, a very critical part of SQL select statement.

Comment: @Parfait.....Thanks........my mistake.....was rushing to get it completed before the end of the day.....Thanks again......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should end up with something that looks more like this:

- alias your table
- remove unneeded parentheses
- move the HAVING to a regular WHERE clause
- put the FROM in the correct place

```
SELECT 
    a.Cust_Name, Sum(a.Amt_Paid) AS SumOfAmt_Paid, Count(a.Unit_Num) AS CountOfUnit_Num 
FROM 
    [MyTable] a
WHERE 
    a.Grp = 'V1' and
    a.Upload_Date = #[somedate]# and
    a.Sub_eEmpl = 'someuser' and 
    a.Cust_Name not like 'Deposit Total*'
GROUP BY a.Cust_Name
```

Comment: @timwilliams...........Thanks worked like a champ and was exactly what I needed...